# How to pull a file from git and put in workspace before the Jenkins build get started

Tags: jenkins

So I'm trying to pull a file from git and put in workspace in order to load that file to be in parameterized job in Jenkins (source value) .property file in order to load choices. I need this operation to be automated. The file part

Comment: You can set an upstream job that runs before your main job which does this.

Comment: can you see this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72188524/how-to-load-git-file-in-parameterized-job-in-jenkins,

Comment: Extensible Choice parameter plugin allows you to run a Groovy script to return choice values. It should be possible to pull a file from Git, read it and return its values as choices.

Comment: @zett42                                                     even if I have a Password for that repo? Will it work ?